# C++ binary is perfectly executing while running with valgrind but failing when run this binary alone

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have a C++ executable, when i run this binary with following command

```
valgrind -v --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --track-origins=yes mybinary -mode init > 5.log 2>&1
```

it is exited with 0, and all the output files generated.

But when I run this binary like

```
mybinary -mode init > 5.log 2>&1
```

it is core dumping in many places (one after another place).

why the beahavior changes when I ran with valgrind ? Does valgrind set any internal environment variables ?

Comment: What does valgrind log say?

Comment: With so little information we can but guess. Mine is, your program exhibits Undefined Behaviour and the fact that it appears to work when run under `valgrind` is mere chance.

Comment: Dumping cores in many places indicates that it's either multithreaded or using fork, which means that the timing will be different when running valgrind (which may also synchronise things in some ways, since I'm sure it has some locks to prevent it from tying itself into knots). Look for race-conditions, and analyse your core-dumps to try to see where it goes.

Comment: Here is the valgrind output


==17831== 2554 errors in context 304 of 413:
==17831== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==17831==    by 0x38CAA077F0: start_thread (in /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so)
==17831==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==17831==    at 0x4A06C8E: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:261)
==17831==    by 0x38CAA077F0: start_thread (in /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so)

Comment: @Mats petersson
you are right my code is using threads.

Comment: So, as the answer below says, valgrind definitely changes the way threads behave. You probably have race-conditions where data is being accessed from one thread before it's been made ready by another thread, or after it's been deleted by some thread, or similar types of issues - these can be quite hard to find, but there's really no easy answer to finding them other than "try to work out why it crashes, and then figure out what the root cause of that is.

Answer (score 1):

As the very Valgrind Manual [says](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.pthreads),

> Valgrind serialises execution so that only one (kernel) thread is running at a time. [...] your program will see very different scheduling when run on Valgrind than it does when running normally. This is both because Valgrind is serialising the threads, and because the code runs so much slower than normal.

Also, you are running the default Valgrind tool, memcheck. You could try using any of the thread-focused tools, like helgrind or DRD, to maybe get something specific about concurrency problems.